# how can i split one variable programmatically?

Tags: ios, variables, split

i have a nsstring like that:

```
Variable1 = x;\n    Variable2 = y;\n    variable3 = z;\n    variable4 = t
```

to make a clear question i am showing nslog of my nsstring:

```
NSLog(@"%@",myNsString);
```

at NSLOG:

```
    Variable1 = x
    Variable2 = y
    variable3 = z
    variable4 = t
```

and i want separate them into different variables.

Comment: What exactly is myNsString?

Comment: You need to parse the string. Split it by '\n' and then each result by the '=' sign. The second part of each array will be the value, while the first one, the keyname. If there is something you don't know how to do about this let me know and I will expand this comment in to a response with the code (but would have to wait for a while).

Comment: Use the componentsSeparatedByString method

Comment: Question is why not use separate strings from the beginning..?

Comment: You can't make a variable from a string. You can parse the NSString to learn that it contains a substring `@"Variable1"`, but you will not be able to create an actual variable called `Variable1`. The best you can do is use `@"Variable1"` as a dictionary key.

Comment: sangony because i am retrieving that string from a server with that form. from @RicardPérezdelCampo and matt's  comment i understand that i have to split my nsString but can you expand your commend with code? or can you suggest me any tutorial about spliting nsstring?

Comment: I am late, sorry! Looks like @ttarules already solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want the x,y,z, and t values in separate strings? And you have them in one massive string? Please try to be more clear if you want help, but this should get you started in the right direction:

```
NSString *yourNSString = @"Variable1 = x;\n    Variable2 = y;\n    variable3 = z;\n    variable4 = t";

NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"=;"];
NSArray *splitter = [yourNSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
NSString *x;
NSString *y;
NSString *z;
NSString *t;

for(int i = 0; i<splitter.count ; i++)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        x = [[splitter objectAtIndex:i]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
        y = [[splitter objectAtIndex:i]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
    else if(i==5)
    {
        z = [[splitter objectAtIndex:i]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
    else if(i==7)
    {
        t = [[splitter objectAtIndex:i]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the perfect answer for my question. thank you.